# How can i bind xml to mvvm wpf?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm

I have a problem. I have wpf mvvm app and I need to bind xml, but I don't know how.

I have there elements model, elements vm, and a view. Everything work, but all of that elements have "some base" model.

```
class ItemModel
{
    public ItemModel(string name, double weight, double sg, double volume)
    {

        Name = name;
        Weight = weight;
        Sg = sg;
        Volume = volume;

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Sg { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }

}
```

This is my VM.

```
class ItemViewModel : BaseVM
{
    public ItemViewModel(string name, double sg, double weight,  double volume)
    {
        Name = name;
        Weight = weight;
        Sg = sg;
        Volume = volume;

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private double _weight;
    public double Weight
    {
         get => _weight;
         set
         {
             _weight = value;

             RaisePropertyChanged();
         }
    }

    private double _sg;
    public double Sg
    {
        get => _sg;
        set
        {
            _sg = value;
            Weight = value * _volume;

            RaisePropertyChanged("Weight");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Sg");
        }
    }


    private double _volume;
    public double Volume
    {
        get => _volume;
        set
        {
            _volume = value;
            _weight = value * _sg;

            RaisePropertyChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged("Weight");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Sg");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainVM

```
class MainViewModel
{
    private DataModel Data;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ListCollectionView FilteredItems { get; set; }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Data = new DataModel();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

    FilteredItems = new ListCollectionView(Items)
    {
        Filter = item => ((ItemViewModel)item).Volume != 0,
        IsLiveFiltering = true,
        LiveFilteringProperties =
        {
            nameof (ItemViewModel.Volume)
        }
    };

        Load();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        foreach (var item in Data.GetItems())
            Items.Add(new ItemViewModel(item.Name, item.Weight, item.Sg, item.Volume));
    }
}
```

I have some "DataModel"

```
class DataModel
{
    public List<ItemModel> GetItems() =>
        new List<ItemModel>
        {
            new ItemModel("Water", 0.00, 1.025, 0.00),
            new ItemModel("Ballast", 0.00, 1.000, 0.00),
            new ItemModel("Oil", 0.00, 1.040, 0.00),
        };
}
```

And this is xml i want to bind instead.

```
<ballast>
  <tank ID="FPTW" Name="Forepeak" Weight="0.00" SG="1.025" Volume="0.00"> </tank>
</ballast>
```

Please help me how can i bind this xml file instead list in DataModel.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: how is your question related to XML?

Comment: Sorry, edited question

Comment: [How to: Bind to XML Data Using an XMLDataProvider and XPath Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-xml-data-using-an-xmldataprovider-and-xpath-queries)

Comment: I'm sorry but this example is for binding to xaml?

Comment: If the xml is constant then I'd usually translate it to and from viewmodel objects and bind them. If you bind directly to xml then you have nowhere to validate and you need converters all over the place.

Comment: No, It's not constant.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to deserialize your XML to "real" objects. In your example you want to have a list of tanks in your programm. The view (XAML) should not know if the "data storage" is a xml file, database or whatever. Just bind to a list of `TankViewModel` (or in your case you named it `ItemViewModel`. Hopefully you don't blow something up with all these tanks....

This is how you deserialize the xml to "real" objects (full working console app:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zCHSmc

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
        foreach(tank t in vm.ListOfTanks.ballast)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.ID);
        }


    }

    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public tanks ListOfTanks
        {
            get
            {
                string xmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><tanks xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">  <ballast><tank><ID>ksj</ID></tank>  </ballast></tanks>";
                tanks allTanks = null;

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(tanks));

                //if you have a xml file you can use serializer.Deserialize("yourFile.xml"); instead of the "in memory stream"

                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlContent))
                {
                    allTanks =(tanks)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
                return allTanks;
            }
        }
    }


    public class tanks
    {
        public tanks()
        {
            ballast = new List<tank>();
        }
        public List<tank> ballast {get;set;} 
    }


    public class tank
    {
        public string ID {get;set;}
    }
}
```